# Sort Algorithm creates error message when changing objects in vector

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

```
#include<vector>;
using namespace std;

int main() {
vector<int>Liste;                       
Liste = { 5,2,3,6,3,4,7 };              
int n = Liste.size();                   
int i, j, k_1, k_2 ;                    
int m_1, m_2 ;                          
for (i; i = 0; i = n - 1) {             
    k_1 = i;                            
    m_1 = Liste[i];                     
    for (j; j = i + 1; j = n) {         
        if (Liste[j] < m_1) {           
            k_2 = j;                    
            m_2 = Liste[j];             
        }
    Liste.insert(k_1, m_2);             
    Liste.insert(k_2 + 1, m_1);         
    Liste.erase(k_1+1);                 
    Liste.erase(k_2 + 2);               
    }
}
cout << Liste << endl;
return 0;
}
```

When running the code an error occures in line 19,20,21,22:
Keine Instanz von Überladene Funktion "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::insert [mit _Ty=int, _Alloc=std::allocator]" stimmt mit der Argumentliste überein

Since i am new to coding i am not sure why this error occures.

Comment: The location argument for both `insert` and `erase` is an iterator, not an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insert` and `erase` methods of `std::vector` take an `iterator` as first parameter, not a simple integer, this is roughly the sens of the error returned by your compiler. It does not find any version of `insert` that takes an `int` as first parameter.

https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/

Anyway you can use this method to achieve what you want to do:

```
Liste.insert(Liste.begin() + k_1, m_2);             
Liste.insert(Liste.begin() + (k_2 + 1), m_1);         
Liste.erase(Liste.begin() + (k_1 + 1));                 
Liste.erase(Liste.begin() + (k_2 + 2))
```